# how to enter correct oauthurl in dreamhouse sample app installation?

Tags: javascript, heroku, oauth, salesforce

I am trying to install dreamhouse sample app and make it to work with messenger bot according to https://github.com/dreamhouseapp/dreamhouse-bot-messenger . I followed the instruction but I could not make it to connect to heroku and salesforce. My heroku logs are here..

```html
2017-03-08T14:50:53.663575+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-03-08T14:50:55.421132+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-03-08T14:50:57.961964+00:00 app[web.1]: > messengerforce@1.0.0 start /app
2017-03-08T14:50:57.961938+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-08T14:50:57.961965+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-03-08T14:50:57.961965+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-08T14:50:58.609162+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 51979
2017-03-08T14:50:58.644820+00:00 app[web.1]: end of file
2017-03-08T14:50:59.133013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-03-08T14:50:59.669067+00:00 app[web.1]: Authentication error
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672167+00:00 app[web.1]: { Error: invalid_grant - authentication failure
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672169+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Request._callback (/app/node_modules/nforce/index.js:865:15)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672170+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Request.self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672170+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672171+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672172+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1081:10)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672173+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672173+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672174+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1001:12)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672176+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672176+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672177+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672175+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672178+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
2017-03-08T14:50:59.672179+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) statusCode: 400 }
```

I have no idea how to enter correct oauth url in salesforce connected app.
I repeat the procedure describe in readme, in case I missed something. I mean I followed the instruction though. Is there anything I missed.

Comment: Sometimes it takes 10 minutes for the Connect App to be ready for use.  Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One answer is the IP Relaxation. By default Salesforce sets new connected app have their IP Relaxation configuration set to 'Enforce IP restrictions'. This means take into account all IP restrictions and enforce them. While you're learning with the Dreamhouse demo, you might just relax the IP restrictions.

To solve this problem through IP restrictions, select 'Manage' on your connected app page.

On the 'edit policies' page, change the 'IP Relaxation' to 'Relax IP restrictions'.

Save the page.

Retry your Slack bot.

This is likely the problem.